# DEfine scala enum with 2 properties

Tags: scala, enums

I have several fields that i want to create enum from but those fields have 2 values: `Valid` and `Not valid`:

```
object MyEnum extends Enumeration
{
    val
    type1, // this type is valid
    type2, // valid
    type3, // valid
    type4, // Not valid
    type5, // Not valid
    type6, // Not valid
    type7  // Not valid 
    = value
}
```

Any suggestion how to distinguish between `Valid` and `Not valid` via code ? or maybe it must separate into 2 enums ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function on the Enum object and use the .toString part of Enumeration.Value

```
object MyEnum extends Enumeration {

    val type1 = Value("valid")
    val type2 = Value("valid")
    val type3 = Value("valid")
    val type4 = Value("Not valid")
    val type5 = Value("Not valid")
    val type6 = Value("Not valid")
    val type7 = Value("Not valid")

    lazy val lookup = this.values.map { n => (n, n.toString == "valid") }.toMap

    def isValid(myEnum: MyEnum.Value) =  lookup.getOrElse(myEnum, false)
}

MyEnum.isValid(MyEnum.type1)                      //> res0: Boolean = true
MyEnum.isValid(MyEnum.type7)                      //> res1: Boolean = false
```

Sources: 
https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.7/src/library/scala/Enumeration.scala#L146
http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Enumeration$Value

Comment: Why i need this enum number ? (for example the number 0 for the first enum)

Comment: @davidhol this is usually generated automactically for each of the enums, but needs specified when specifying the `name` paramter.  Probably note needed for this specific use-case.  There is also https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.7/src/library/scala/Enumeration.scala#L139 
` 
@param i    An integer that identifies this value at run-time. It must be
   *             unique amongst all values of the enumeration.
`

Comment: @davidhol I updated the example to not specify the index and let the Enumeration define it with nextId in the overloaded method.

Answer (score 0):

There's a different pattern you could use that does not extend Enumeration but acts similarly:

```
object MyEnum extends Serializable {
  abstract sealed class MyEnum(
    val ordinal: Int, val isValid: Boolean
  ) extends Ordered[MyEnum] with Serializable {
    def compare(that: MyEnum) = that.ordinal compare this.ordinal

    def toInt: Int = this.ordinal
  }

  case object Type1 extends MyEnum(0, true)
  case object Type2 extends MyEnum(1, true)
  case object Type3 extends MyEnum(2, true)
  case object Type4 extends MyEnum(3, false)
  case object Type5 extends MyEnum(4, false)
  case object Type6 extends MyEnum(5, false)
  case object Type7 extends MyEnum(6, false)

  def fromInt(i: Int): MyEnum = values.find(_.ordinal == i).get

  val values = Set(
    Type1, Type2, Type3, Type4, Type5, Type6, Type7
  )
}
```

This way you are able to assign in a way like `val myEnum: MyEnum.MyEnum = MyEnum.Type1` similar to your example above and you will have access to `myEnum.isValid`. Similarly you can access it ordinally with the `fromInt` method. Such as `MyEnum.fromInt(0).isValid`. If you provide some more context on what you're trying to do with the values I may be able to provide a better solution. Hope this helps.

Comment: I am reading drop down list from html page using selenium and this list have several options that some of them valid and some not, this options is require to submit this form, i want to fill this form automatically and if this option is valid the final status after the form save will be different then not valid.